# How do i Make a javascript work properly on opera?

Tags: javascript, opera

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function TextDefine(val){
    var i= 0;                
var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = "[img]" + array1[i] + "[/img]";
}
val.value = array1.join("");
                        }
                        </script>
```

The script above is suppose to be adding a prefix and suffix to multiple lines in a text area.

```
<textarea onClick="SelectAll('data');"  name="data" id="data" cols="100" rows="20" ></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'))" />
```

example:

```
[img]first line[/img]
[img]second line[/img]
```

But in opera browser, the output is like this:

```
[img]first line
[/img][img]second line
[/img]
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: if i were to change the code, anyone who can provide me a new one that would work properly in opera? :( sorry i'm javascript noob

Comment: Seems like opera's `split` function is not removing the seperator from the string.

Comment: You need to amend the question title, this is nothing to do with javascript not working correctly in Opera. It's to do with your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i fixed it :D

i made the line

```
var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
```

to

```
var array1 = val.value.split("\r\n");
```

Then the line

```
array1[i] = "[img]" + array1[i] + "[/img]";
```

to

```
array1[i] = "[img]" + array1[i] + "[/img]\r\n";
```

It's fixed now :) Geez i solved my own probem :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this coming from a textarea? Opera uses \r\n as a line separator in textareas, so try using `var array1 = val.value.split(/\r?\n/);`.